# Transform columns to row indexes with pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following csv file:

[image]

I want to transform that into this one:

[image]

Is there a simple pandas oneliner that can do that kind of transformations? Because I was starting to write a complex for loop for it but something in my mind says pandas can do this really quick :)

Thanks :)

Comment: `df.melt('Date', var_name='airspace', value_name='color')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang what if I have for every airspace ('afdeling' in columns) an extra column (for example airspace_sensor_value) and I want a third column with those values? (that corresponds the airspace and the date)